# Linux Mint 20 TTY 1-6 blinking cursor, GUI at tty7 works normally

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, tty, cursor

I have a custom PC build (AMD Ryzen 3800x, ASUS TUF GAMING X570-PLUS mobo, Nvidia 1660 TI, 16GB ddr4 3200mhz RAM) running Linux Mint 20 (recently released), kernel 5.4.0-39-generic. While it works normally, the 1st TTY just has the LM splash screen spinning (like when it's booting) and the TTYs 1 to 6 are black screen with a blinking cursor.

Other answers I've seen report this issue with Nvidia proprietary drivers, which I do have (driver ver 440) but I'm unsure how to fix this. Booting with `nomodeset` as a kernel parameter does nothing and has no effect at all. Bear in mind I can freely switch between TTYs (while they all have a blinking cursor and a splash screen for TTY1) and get back to the GUI on TTY7 like normal. Is there a way to get the TTY's back up like it was before?

As far as I recall, running LM19.3 with the *same* Nvidia drivers keeps the TTYs working - but if there's a fix to using LM20 then I will be more than happy to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some messing around, I've found the fix for this situation. Removing `splash` from the kernel params lets me access the TTYs just like normal.

I noticed TTY1 had the splash screen constantly there so first removing `quiet splash` with success, and then just `splash` (which also worked) showed me that `splash` was indeed the issue. As previously mentioned I have used `nomodeset` without any help and some online said **they could still use the TTYs, just without seeing the text**. This was NOT the case for me, and I could not use any of the 6 TTYs.

Whether this is indeed NVIDIA driver related, I don't know. Hope this helps someone else though.